# MIPS: determine if a list of test scores are pass/fail

Tags: list, math, mips

I am writing a MiPS program that will examine a list of 15 test scores. And it is going to input from the terminal.Well, the passing criterion is the score of 50. the ouptuts to the terminal will include the scores in each category and the number of students passing and failing. with input prompts and output statements...Below is the program i wrote but it didnt work....Please i need....i dont know if i m doing it wrong..

```
.globl main
.text
```

main:
    li $t0, 0           #counter for passing grades
    la $t1, pass            #pointer for pass array
    li $t2, 0           #counter for failing grades
    la $t3, fail            #pointer for pass array
    li $t4, 0           #overall counter
    li $t5, 0
    li $t6, 0

loop:
    li $v0, 4           #system call for print string
    la $a0, prompt          #load string
    syscall

```
li $v0, 5           #system call for read integer
syscall             #read integer

bltu $v0, 50, else      #if $v0 < 50 branch to else (failing grade)
sw $v0, 0($t1)          #store word in pass array
addi $t1, $t1, 4        #t1 = t1 + 4 (increment pass pointer)
addi $t0, $t0, 1        #t0 = t0 + 1 (increment pass counter)
b l_end             #branch over else statement
```

else:
    sw $v0, 0($t3)          #store word in fail array
    addi $t3, $t3, 4        #t3 = t3 + 4 (increment fail pointer)
    addi $t2, $t2, 1        #t1 = t1 + 1 (increment fail counter)

l_end:
    addi $t4, $t4, 1        #increment overall counter
    bltu $t4, 15, loop      #if t4 <= 15 branch to loop

## output counts

```
li $v0, 4           #system call for print string
la $a0, o_pasc          #load string
syscall             #output "Number of Passing Scores:

la $v0, 1           #system call for print integer
add $a0, $t0, 0         #load value of pass counter into $a0
syscall             #output value

li $v0, 4           #system call for print string
la $a0, o_fasc          #load string
syscall             #output "Number of Failing Scores: "

la $v0, 1           #system call for print string
add $a0, $t2, 0         #load value of fail counter into $a0
syscall             #output value
```

## output passing scores

```
li $v0, 4           #setup output   
la $a0, o_pass          #setup text
syscall             #output string o_pass

la $t1, pass            #load address of pass pointer to t1
lw $a0, 0($t1)          #load word at $t1 into $a0
li $v0, 1           #system call for print integer
```

loop_a:
    bleu $t0, $t5, lp_a_end     #if t0 <= t5 branch to lp_a_end
    syscall             #output single score

```
li $v0, 4           #system call for print string
la $a0, o_coma          #load string
syscall             #ouput comma and space

li $v0, 1           #setup output
addi $t1, $t1, 4        #move pointer down by 1 word
lw $a0, 0($t1)          #move word at pointer into $a0
addi $t5, $t5, 1        #add 1 to counter

b loop_a            #branch to top
```

lp_a_end:

## output failing scores

```
la $t5, 0           #clear t5 (counter)
li $v0, 4           #setup output
la $a0, o_fail          #setup text
syscall             #output string o_fail

la $t3, fail            #load address for fail pointer into $t3
lw $a0, 0($t3)          #load word at mem addy $t3 into $a0
li $v0, 1           #system call for print integer
```

loop_b:
    bleu $t2, $t5, lp_b_end     #if t2 <= t5 branch to lp_a_end
    syscall             #output single score

```
li $v0, 4           #system call for print string
la $a0, o_coma          #load string
syscall             #output comma and space

li $v0, 1           #setup output
addi $t3, $t3, 4        #move pointer down by 1 word
lw $a0, 0($t3)          #load word from mem addy $t3 to $a0
addi $t5, $t5, 1        #add 1 to counter

b loop_b            #branch to top
```

lp_b_end:

## end

```
li $v0, 4           #setup output
la $a0, o_brk           #setup text
syscall             #output line break

li $v0, 10          #loads 10 to $v0
syscall             #ends program
```

Comment: You should edit this, there are some parts of code that are unreadable (exagerating, i know)

Answer (score 3):

"A deja vu is usually a glitch in the Matrix"

Pretty sure i've seen this around:

[MIPS program to determine pass/fail for test grades](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804315/mips-program-need-help)

**EDIT**: Some advice: Try to simplify things. Build your program bit by bit. For example, try to avoid syscalls, use hardcoded inputs to test your comparing logic. Then, go for syscalls. Are you using arrays correctly? I've seen that you keep two separate counters for indexing the array, and keeping count of the elements inside it. I think that that is error prone. Maybe you should use the counter to index the array (multiplying it by 4). Follow the link, i'll be happy to help if any specific doubts appear.

I don't like SPIM simulator much. I know that many universities use it for their courses, but i think that is a mistake, since it is a very limited environment.

**ANOTHER EDIT (by "popular" demand)**:
 I've read your code for a while, and i noticed some things.

- You load values into registers for comparison against zero. Don't do this, use the $zero register.

  li $t5,0

  li $t6.0

are used in

```
bleu $t0,$t5,lp_a_end       #if t0 <= t5 branch to lp_a_end
```

should be

```
bleu $t0,$zero,lp_a_end
```

- Usage of instructions

  bltu $v0, 50, else              #if $v0 < 50 branch to else (failing grade)

branch instructions take two registers and a label. Not register, inmediate, label

Should be:

```
   li   $t5,50
   bltu $v0,$t5,else
```

My guess is that you are complicating yourself in vain with the syscalls. Why are you fancying your output when you cant get it to work? In addition to that, once you start preparing for a syscall, execute it. Dont put a branch instruction in the middle, like in

```
        la $t3, fail                    #load address for fail pointer into $t3
        lw $a0, 0($t3)                  #load word at mem addy $t3 into $a0
        li $v0, 1        
loop_b: bleu $t2, $t5, lp_b_end         #if t2 <= t5 branch to lp_a_end 
        syscall                         #output single score
```

This is quite confusing. Maybe you should try something like:

```
#Is there anything to print in the array? If not, goto lp_b_end
bleu $t2,$zero,lp_b_end

#Ok, we know we are not pointing at an invalid position of the array.       
la $t3, fail                    #load address for fail pointer into $t3
lw $a0, 0($t3)                  #load word at mem addy $t3 into $a0
li $v0, 1 
syscall
```

Finally, try to keep a convention when you use syscalls. For example, use registers $a0 and $v0 only for syscalls. Dont use them for anything else. If you read an integer into $v0, then move it to $t0 before doing anything else.

That's all i can think of right now. As someone said in the dupe post (Rob Kennedy), try asking your instructor as well, that's why he gets paid  (i'm not your instructor, just a helping hand).

Comment: @Tom, just wanted to say that you consistently give out good MIPS answers.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: Hi Tom, i just wanted to thank you very much all your help. well, you have seen this question before. Although, i have been working on this for like a week and half now, but still can't figure it out. tom you can see that i tried my best and still it dosent work for me. i followed the solution you provided  on above link and it makes me even more confused. I know you dont like to give away code away, but Please i m begging you to currect me to see where i am having trouble based on the program i wrote so far.....i will appriciate any help....ihope to hear from you.